# Suspended sediment yield

Tags: geology, sedimentology, vegetation

I am finding it difficult to understand the factors that affect the suspended sediment yield in an area. I was thinking of the Rouse number and how it is affected by the particle diameter, slope and flow depth. Although I could not correlate a suspended sediment yield with the vegetation cover, soil type and rainfall intensity. Could someone give an example where an area will contain high suspended sediment yield and what the properties of this area are going to be?

Comment: Can you access your university library?

Answer (score 2):

An example of an area with a high suspended sediment yield could be a steep mountainous region with a combination of specific properties. Let's consider the following characteristics:

Steep Slopes: High suspended sediment yield is often associated with areas having steep slopes. Steep slopes increase the erosive power of flowing water, leading to a higher likelihood of sediment detachment and transport.

Unconsolidated or Loose Soil: The area should have soil that is easily erodible, such as loose or unconsolidated sediment, which can be readily transported by flowing water. This can occur in regions with extensive weathering or areas with recent geological activity, such as landslides or glacial retreat.

Sparse Vegetation Cover: In an area with limited vegetation cover, the soil is exposed and vulnerable to erosion by rainfall or runoff. Vegetation plays a crucial role in stabilizing soil and reducing erosion by intercepting rainfall, dissipating energy, and binding soil particles together with their roots.

High Rainfall Intensity: Intense or heavy rainfall events can contribute to increased suspended sediment yield. High rainfall intensity leads to greater surface runoff, which can carry more sediment from the landscape into rivers or streams.